# StackScraper - export questions as JSON or HTML

Tags: script, javascript, coffeescript

### About

StackScraper is a user script that adds HTML and JSON export options to each question. The JSON loosely resembles the API format and includes the HTML and markdown bodies of all posts, as well as their comments and vote counts (if you have permission to view them). The HTML displays the content similarly to Stack Exchange and includes the necessary attribution. Comments are included, but initially hidden.

[image]

As an example, here are the [JSON](https://s3.amazonaws.com/23e9f5/87d65ee1-05e9-44aa-bdca-7aed385d27f3%23question-3126096.json) and [HTML](https://s3.amazonaws.com/23e9f5/2d615e2a-f8e2-45df-9263-67d5cd17c35b%23question-3126096.html) dumps of [a deleted question](//stackoverflow.com/q/3126096).

[image]

#### License

Released under the [MIT Open Source License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

#### Installation

[**Click here**](https://github.com/extensions/stackscraper/raw/gh-pages/stackscraper.user.js) to install or update StackScraper.

#### Platforms

- Google Chrome, probably
- Mozilla Firefox + [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), possibly

(Not well-tested yet.)

### Contact

StackScraper was written by me, Jeremy Banks. Feedback and bug reports can be posted as comments or answers below.

### Code

StackScraper was written in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). You can view or contribute to the source [here on GitHub](https://github.com/extensions/stackscraper).

Comment: **Bug** Mangles owner of [this wiki question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553/track-your-reputation?noredirect=1).

Comment: **TODO** Fetch revisions list for wiki posts in order to always correctly determine owner/editors.

Comment: **TODO** Stop making requests as soon as you get blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The script is not working.

1. `.post-menu` is now `.js-post-menu`
2. BlobBuilder was deprecated.

On my copy, I applied corrections to fix the above. That was enough to get an output. There are still other changes, like updating the other classes' names, but I'm unfamiliar with CoffeeScript.

## Related

- [Rob W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15031019/1595451) to [How to replace the deprecated BlobBuilder with the new Blob constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15030906/1595451)